# How to extract a frame from a base64 encoded gif?

Tags: base64, frame, gif

I converted a .gif file to base64 string, and now I want to cut this string in order to represent only one frame of the gif. How do I do this? There is some character used as frame separator? Or some resolution calculation?

Comment: This is an animated gif?  How much control do you have over the conversion?  Base64 does a *sort of* encryption on the string, so the only way I see of getting to the frame is to decode it.

Comment: I am using it on the tag <img src="<base64String>"/> of a IONIC application, I only have access to the base64 string.

Comment: Hmmm...that sounds like a real tough problem to solve.  Maybe there are canvas image rendering options that would allow you to save the current appearance?  Then you'd show the image at the frame you want and export from canvas to a new base64?